# Figma Plugin - help programmatically creating text style

Tags: promise, figma

I am trying to create Figma Text styles via a plugin that reads from my design tokens. The problem I am having is when setting the custom font, the promise to load it does not resolve, so it seems to stall the function.

Am I missing something here?

```js
async function createNewTextStyle(token) {
    // Style does not yet exist, so create it
    const newStyle = figma.createTextStyle();

    // the new text style is preloaded with Roboto, so we need to load that
    await figma.loadFontAsync(newStyle.fontName);
    
    // This is the font i want to set my text style to.
    // it seems that this promise never resolves (or errors).
    await figma.loadFontAsync({
        family: 'SF Pro Text',
        style: 'Regular',
    });

// Set the properties of the text style
    newStyle.fontName = {
        family: 'SF Pro Text',
        style: 'Regular',
    };
    newStyle.name = designToken.name;
    newStyle.fontSize = designToken.value;
    newStyle.lineHeight = { value: designToken.lineHeight, unit: 'PIXELS' };
}
```

Comment: What plugin are you developing?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... it looks like you're missing the `.then` callback that's usually used to handle a promise resolution.

Also, your variable name `designToken` is not defined in your code, but you're using `token` (from your function parameters).

Try this in your plugin:

```js
async function createNewTextStyle(token) {
    // Style does not yet exist, so create it
    const newStyle = figma.createTextStyle();

    // the new text style is preloaded with Roboto, so we need to load that
    await figma.loadFontAsync(newStyle.fontName);
    
    // This is the font i want to set my text style to.
    figma.loadFontAsync({
        family: 'SF Pro Text',
        style: 'Regular',
    }).then(() => {
        // Set the properties of the text style
        newStyle.fontName = {
            family: 'SF Pro Text',
            style: 'Regular',
        };
        newStyle.name = token.name;
        newStyle.fontSize = token.value;
        newStyle.lineHeight = { value: token.lineHeight, unit: 'PIXELS' };
    });
}
```